# Safari can't open the page because the address is invalid

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, deep-linking

I receive a URL from the server, from which I form a deep link and it works fine on android. However, on the iOS platform - this does not work with the error that is indicated in the title

Here are all the settings that I did for iOS -
[image: 1]
[image: 2]

And here is the code that works on android -

```
getDynamicLink(String dynamicLinkODengi) async {
      final dynamicLinkParams = DynamicLinkParameters(
        link: Uri.parse(dynamicLinkODengi),
        uriPrefix: "https://ecocity.page.link",
        androidParameters:
            const AndroidParameters(packageName: "com.example.app.android"),
        iosParameters: const IOSParameters(bundleId: "com.example.app.ios"),
      );
      final dynamicLink =
          await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.buildLink(dynamicLinkParams);
      return dynamicLink;
    }
```

and

```
_launchURL(Uri link) async {
    if (await canLaunchUrl(link)) {
      
      await launchUrl(link, mode:
      LaunchMode.externalApplication);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $link';
    }
  }
```

error in image [image: error]

In the FireBase project settings, I specified all the data that was needed - bundle id, app store id, and team id

Comment: This may not be your solution, but you can validate the URL with - 
`UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(<YOUR_URL>)`